# mysql query to group record and generate custom columns

Tags: mysql, sql, database

So i have a table named "log" with the following columns,

```
id, endpoint ,response ,group

SAMPLE DATA.
1. endpoint1 ,{"last_name":"data here"}  ,1234
2. endpoint2 ,{"first_name":"data here"} ,1234
3. endpoint3 ,{"dob":"12-21-2301"}       ,1234
```

what I want to achieve is to write a query that can generate a record grouped by the "
group" column and the final output should be something like this.

```
{"last_name","data here","first_name":"data here","dob":"12-21-2301"}
```

for each record with each key been a column.
Thank you

Comment: What is **precise** MySQL version?

Comment: the mysql version is  8.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE
cte1 AS ( SELECT response, 
                 `group`,
                 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY `group`) rn
          FROM log ),
cte2 AS ( SELECT response, 
                 `group`,
                 rn
          FROM cte1
          WHERE rn = 1 
        UNION ALL
          SELECT JSON_MERGE_PRESERVE(cte1.response, cte2.response), 
                 cte1.`group`,
                 cte1.rn
          FROM cte2
          JOIN cte1 USING (`group`)
          WHERE cte2.rn + 1 = cte1.rn )
SELECT DISTINCT
       FIRST_VALUE(response) OVER (PARTITION BY `group` ORDER BY rn DESC) responses, 
       `group`
FROM cte2;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=913b1923d7d5dbc7e42baeefb6e6ec86

Comment: thank you, this worked